# Not getting IP Address due to firewall

Tags: ip, firewall

i am trying to implement personalization in my website using the IP address. but because of firewall i'am no able to get the user's original ip address. I tried following lines of code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these two

Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
or
Request.UserHostAddress

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address of the machine and not the proxy use the following code

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];